# Android emulator can't be started

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

I've made some Android emulator device, and try to execute it. I've got the following errors:

```
02-18 05:46:39.070        99-99/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ ERROR: failed to open framebuffer (No such file or directory), aborting
02-18 05:46:39.070        99-99/? A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00000063 (code=-6), thread 99 (surfaceflinger)
02-18 05:46:43.430      137-137/? E/cutils﹕ Failed to read /data/.layout_version: No such file or directory
02-18 05:46:43.430      137-137/? E/installd﹕ Could not create directories; exiting.
02-18 05:46:43.710      138-138/? E/keystore﹕ chdir: /data/misc/keystore: No such file or directory
02-18 05:46:44.160      134-134/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ hwcomposer module not found
02-18 05:46:44.160      134-134/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ ERROR: failed to open framebuffer (No such file or directory), aborting
02-18 05:46:44.170      134-134/? A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00000086 (code=-6), thread 134 (surfaceflinger)
02-18 05:46:48.530      150-150/? E/cutils﹕ Failed to read /data/.layout_version: No such file or directory
02-18 05:46:48.530      150-150/? E/installd﹕ Could not create directories; exiting.
02-18 05:46:48.670      151-151/? E/keystore﹕ chdir: /data/misc/keystore: No such file or directory
02-18 05:46:49.260      147-147/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ hwcomposer module not found
02-18 05:46:49.260      147-147/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ ERROR: failed to open framebuffer (No such file or directory), aborting
02-18 05:46:49.260      147-147/? A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00000093 (code=-6), thread 147 (surfaceflinger)
```

How can I fix it? My device doesn't run. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the one you made and using one of the pre-made device emulators? Assuming you're using Eclipse

Answer (score 54):

While creating emulator check the option "Use Host GPU" at the bottom and try..
For those who cannot find the "Use Host GPU" please refer to:['Snapshot' and 'Use Host GPU' options missing from AVD settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38182131/snapshot-and-use-host-gpu-options-missing-from-avd-settings)

Comment: Worked perfect for me.

Comment: I love you. 6 Hours and you saved my life

Comment: This worked for me, thank you. Do you know what the issue was?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like issue with high resolution 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76948

try lowring the resolution

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to add to

> While creating emulator check the option "Use Host GPU" at the bottom and try..

Make sure that your `TARGET API` of your project is the same as your `EMULATOR's` version.

E.g If your project is targetting 4.4.2 then make sure your emulator is set to 4.4.2 :)

Answer (score -4):

Try it in Ubuntu 14.04

1. Install JDK 7
2. Install SDK Manager
3. Install Android Studio
4. Create Virtual Device using AVD Manager

Enjoy it!