# 'Snapshot' and 'Use Host GPU' options missing from AVD settings

Tags: android, android-studio

I just started using Android Studio, looking at some tutorials online, there's supposed to be those 2 options when creating or editing Android Virtual Device, now in my case I don't see it anywhere.

[image]

Is the 'Use Host GPU' have been renamed to 'Hardware - GLES 2.0' in 'Emulated Performance'?

If so then where's the option for enabling Snapshot? Or is the new Android Studio just enables/disables it by default?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like Hardware GLES 2.0 is using host GPU. Should make your emulated device run faster.

I am lost on the Snapshot option. It isn't featured on developer.android.com. I did find an instance about emulation where it was mentioned, "Caution: Do not select the Snapshot: Enabled option. Snapshots are not supported for emulators with graphics acceleration enabled".

Answer (score 16):

[image: Hope this helps]

Select 'Software GLES 2.0' to disable host GPU

Comment: Great! this helped me!

Comment: But after choosing software GLES its showing "performing clean boot snapshot doent exist" in emulator screen. Please tell me how to resolve this issue.